# Appending extra key value to an existing list of dictionaries

Tags: python, json, file

I have an list of dictionary to which I want to append 3 additional key value pairs.

List of dictionary

```
[
    {'by': 270.74, 'by_l': [270.74], 'date_time': '2019-07-08 14:21:42', 'name': 'test_1', 't_avg': 29.69, 't_runs': [29.69]},
    {'by': 432.17, 'by_l': [432.17], 'date_time': '2019-07-08 14:21:47', 'name': 'test_2', 't_avg': 47.39, 't_runs': [47.39]}
]
```

Thing that has to be appended

```
{'max': 70, 'min': 30, 'std_dev': 15.01},
{'max': 70, 'min': 30, 'std_dev': 15.01}`
```

so that it looks something like this :

```
[
    {'by': 270.74, 'by_l': [270.74], 'date_time': '2019-07-08 14:21:42', 'name': 'test_1', 't_avg': 29.69, 't_runs': [29.69], 'max': 70, 'min': 30, 'std_dev': 15.016218454280247},
    {'by': 432.17, 'by_l': [432.17], 'date_time': '2019-07-08 14:21:47', 'name': 'test_2', 't_avg': 47.39, 't_runs': [47.39], 'max': 70, 'min': 30, 'std_dev': 15.01}
]
```

Since I am storing `max`, `min` and `std_dev` in their respective lists, I have tried doing the following:

```
past_data = {
    'max': 0,
    'min': 0,
    'std_dev': 0
}

for x in range(0, len(max_list)):
    past_data['max'] = max_list[x]
    past_data['min'] = min_list[x]
    past_data['std_dev'] = std_dev_list[x]
    output_data.append(past_data)
```

But I get the following output :

```
[
    {'by': 270.74, 'by_l': [270.74], 'date_time': '2019-07-08 14:21:42', 'name': 'test_1', 't_avg': 29.69, 't_runs': [29.69]},
    {'by': 432.17, 'by_l': [432.17], 'date_time': '2019-07-08 14:21:47', 'name': 'test_2', 't_avg': 47.39, 't_runs': [47.39]},{'max': 70, 'min': 30, 'std_dev': 15.01}, {'max': 70, 'min': 30, 'std_dev': 15.01}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two questions here:

1) How do you iterate over two lists in sync?

2) Given two dictionaries, how do you merge one into the other?

For the first, `zip` is usually best:

```
for (d1, d2) in zip(list_of_dictionary, max_list):
```

If you want to use an explicit list index, it'd look like:

```
for i in range(0, math.min(len(list_of_dictionary), len(max_list)):
    d1 = list_of_dictionary[i]
    d2 = max_list[i]
```

For the second, use `update` to copy all key/value pairs from one dict into the other. This mutates the updated dictionary, so there's no need to build a new list.

```
    d1.update(d2)
```

If you wanted to avoid editing the initial dictionary, it's a little harder. One way is something like:

```
    copied_data = {}
    copied_data.update(d1)
    # or just copied_data = d1.copy()
    copied_data.update(d2)
    output_data.append(copied_data)
```

There are more concise ways to build a new dict from shallow copies of existing ones, but personally I think they're harder to follow.

That does a shallow copy, which is probably fine but could have odd consequences with your `by_l` values - it'll copy a reference to the same list object into the new dict, so mutating that value would also mutate the original. That's probably out of scope for this discussion, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in one line

```
output_data = [{**a, **b} for a, b in zip(list_of_dictionary, max_list)]
```

this takes each pair of dictionaries from your old list and the new list and combines the two dictionaries into one

Comment: by max_list do you mean `{'max': 70, 'min': 30, 'std_dev': 15.01},
{'max': 70, 'min': 30, 'std_dev': 15.01}` ?

Comment: @ArYad yes thats the one